# How to initialize a constexpr class using an initializer list?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have written a template class representing large integers as follows:

```
template<typename ElementType, uint32_t ElementNum>
class Integer final{
    //Some public function.
private:
    ElementType value_[ElementNum];
};
```

I need to create a compile-time constant of type Integer<uint32_t, 2>. To achieve this, I added various constexpr constructors, but using any of them results in compilation errors.

```
template<typename ElementType, uint32_t ElementNum>
class Integer final{
public:
    constexpr Integer(const std::initializer_list<ElementType> &l){
        auto iter = l.begin();
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ElementNum; i++) {
            if (iter != l.end()) {
                value_[i] = *iter;
                iter++;
            } else {
                value_[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    constexpr Integer(const std::array<ElementType, ElementNum> &v){
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ElementNum; i++) {
            value_[i] = v[i];
        }
    };
    constexpr explicit Integer(const ElementType data[ElementNum]){
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ElementNum; i++) {
            value_[i] = data[i];
        }
    };
private:
    ElementType value_[ElementNum];
};
int main() {
    //error: expression must have a constant value
    //constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> a({1, 2});
    //                                 ^
    //note #2703-D: cannot call non-constexpr function "Integer<ElementType, ElementNum>::Integer(const std::initializer_list<ElementType> &) [with ElementType=uint32_t, ElementNum=2U]" 
    //constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> a({1, 2});
    //                                 ^
    constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> a({1, 2});
    constexpr std::array<uint32_t, 2> t({1,2});
    //error: expression must have a constant value
    //constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> b(t);
    //                                 ^
    //note #2703-D: cannot call non-constexpr function "Integer<ElementType, ElementNum>::Integer(const std::array<ElementType, ElementNum> &) [with ElementType=uint32_t, ElementNum=2U]"
    //constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> b(t);
    //                                 ^
    constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> b(t);
    constexpr uint32_t p[2] = {1,2};
    //error: expression must have a constant value
    //constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> c(p);
    //                                 ^
    //note #2703-D: cannot call non-constexpr function "Integer<ElementType, ElementNum>::Integer(const ElementType *) [with ElementType=uint32_t, ElementNum=2U]"
    //constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> c(p);
    //                                 ^
    constexpr Integer<uint32_t, 2> c(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please guide me on how to modify this Integer class and construct a compile-time constant of this type?

compiler:gcc 9.4.0
c++ standard: 14

Comment: There are no issues with compilation using Clang, but GCC produces errors. How should I modify it to ensure correct compilation across all C++ standard-compliant compilers?

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: Looks like a bug either in clang or GCC.

Comment: The workaround for gcc is to initialize your array at the beginning, for example: `ElementType value_[ElementNum] = {};`. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E9MYhxf3P) This should be a clang bug IMO.

Comment: Both gcc and msvc rejects this. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j44KbG55r)

Comment: Note that all compilers accept the code in C++20. So looks like something changed in C++20 maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please guide me on how to modify this Integer class and construct a compile-time constant of this type?

This seems to be a compiler bug. A workaround to make this work with all compilers is to replace `ElementType value_[ElementNum];` with `ElementType value_[ElementNum] = {};`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qqbYKrzzK)

---

Another workaround is to use `std::array`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6K9x864rG). Here we replace `ElementType value_[ElementNum];` with `std::array<ElementType, ElementNum> value_;`.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please guide me on how to modify this Integer class and construct a compile-time constant of this type?

The language itself can help you. What you're trying to do has already be done, and done well. It has been done for `std::array` for instance, let us leverage this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename ElementType, std::size_t ElementNum>
class Integer final{
public:
    template<class... T>
    constexpr Integer(T... values)
        : value_{ std::forward<ElementType>(values)... }
    {}
private:
    std::array<ElementType, ElementNum> value_;
};

#include <cstdint>
int main()
{
    constexpr Integer<std::uint32_t, 2> integer{1, 2};
    (void) integer;
}
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xWrKh34G5)